# React app deployment error in npm development build

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm developing a react application.When I try to deploy it using npm start it is showing that your development build is not optimized.Use npm run build to install production build.

Answer (score 0):

The message means exactly what it says. Use `npm run build` to make a production build, and serve those built static files with some http server like nginx or apache. Your current `npm start` is making a debug build, and probably serving it with a hot reloading server.

To identify the differences between a production build and a debug build, check out your underlying build system and its configurations.